# How do I complete this code to calculate the "escape velocity" of earth?

Tags: syntax, syntax-error

I know != is supposed to be changed to ==, but when I run the code again, I think it is trying to tell me the whole [if mass == Decimal('0') or radius == Decimal('0'):] command is incorrect. I know there is at least one more syntax error in this code, but I can't get python to tell me what it is without fixing the [if mass == Decimal ('0') or radius == Decimal('0'):] command first.

```py
decimal import *

GRAVITATIONAL_CONSTANT = Decimal('6.67384E-11')


# Credit to http://codingwithnumbers.blogspot.com/ for this function
def escape_velocity(mass, radius):
    '''Calculates the delta-V escape velocity.

    Returns delta-V in meters per second for the escape
    velocity for a given object given its mass in kilograms
    and its radius in meters.'''

    #IMPORTANT: mass and radius should be checked to see if they are exactly equal to zero, using the correct comparison operator
    # If either are exactly equal to 0, this function will return None
        if mass != Decimal('0') or radius != Decimal('0'):
    return None

    # Calculate the result using correct formulas
    # NOTE: Syntax errors on one line may mistakenly cause an error to appear on another
    result = Decimal((2 * GRAVITATIONAL_CONSTANT * mass) / radius
        result = result.sqrt()

        return result


earth_mass_in_kg = Decimal('5.9736E24')
earth_radius_in_meters = Decimal('6371000')

    print("The escape velocity of Earth is {} m/s".format(round(escape_velocity(earth_mass_in_kg, earth_radius_in_meters))))
```

Comment: I'm no Python expert, but running this code through a python compiler shows numerous indentation errors and only indentation errors.  I don't know if the errors are in your source code or only in this stackflow page, but it's worth checking.

In addition, please include the error message in your question as that helps greatly in fully understanding the problem.